# Crossing the boundary of a subset of $ℝ^2$.

Tags: general-topology, plane-curves

Given a subset $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, let us say that a point $p$ lying in the boundary of $U$ is a **simple boundary point** if there
exists a continuous curve $γ:(-1,1)→\mathbb{R}^2$, such that

- $γ(0)=p$,
- $γ(t)∈\text{int}(U)$, for all $t∈(0,1)$, and
- $γ(t)∈\text{ext}(U)$, for all $t∈(-1,0)$,

where *int* and *ext* refer, respectively, to interior and exterior.

Assuming that  $U$ is a nonempty open set, and that its exterior is nonempty, can we guarantee the existence of simple
boundary points?   If so, can we also prove that the set of simple boundary points is large in any reasonable sense?

PS.  It is not hard to see that there is a point in the boundary of the  [Warsaw circle](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Warsaw+circle) which is not simple.

Comment: There are open sets whose boundary contains no arc (mimic the chain construction of the pseudoarc, but with circular chains, and take that as boundary). This looks like a good candidate for a counterexample but I cannot prove it works